# Database master-slave replication error

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I am trying to replicate my mysql database using the master slave replication. On the slave machine, when i try to run this query, i get stuck.

```
mysqldump -h 10.124.2.34 bank --password='' --user='root' | mysql bank --password='' --user='root'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get stuck"?  The command never completes?  You do not know what to do next?

Comment: I ran this command: mysqldump -h 10.128.2.34 bank --user=root | mysql bank --user=root; and i am getting a syntax error. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: The master and slave currently use the same username (root) and no password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Total DB dump :**

mysqldump -uroot -h  -p pwd -P   db_name | mysql -uroot -p pwd -P       db_name

**Only Table copy**

mysqldump -uroot -h  -p pwd -P   db_name  | mysql -uroot -p pwd -P       db_name

It's working for me.